# linkedin API framework 403 error for searches in PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm using this linkedin api framework I found online which was extremely helpful but this issue I'm having is I'm able to access the information in my account after I login and am redirected to the demo.php page but there's a facebook employee search that is returning a 403 Access denied.

linkedin site says that i don't have access or that the throttle is full.  I can see it not being able to access it because it can't read my oAuth code.

After doing a var_dump on the variable that I want to echo, it's returning a null.  My guess is that it's not reading the authorization but when I var_dump the $linkedin variable, the oAuth is there.

Like I said i'm able to get output when it comes to my profile but when I try to make other calls, that's when the error arises.

If it helps I had to put CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, flase to the code in order to access the login page.

everything works fine except this one thing.  The login, the redirect and me being able to access my own information.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks

Edit - I just tried out the simple-linkedin and I'm still getting the 403 error.
So it's got to be the permission.  In all the demo pages they are able to access this information, how come I can not?  I login, even people in my contacts I can't search.

Figured it out.  in the linkedin.php file, you have to modify the '= $this->base_url . "/v1/..."
to what you are looking for.

Hope this helps with someone.

EDIT-------I'm still getting the 403 error when I try to search people.  Can someone explain why this is happening and how other people are able to access this information.

this is the line that i'm using :
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,headline))

Answer (score 0):

From the asker's edit to his original question:

> Figured it out. in the linkedin.php file, you have to modify the '= $this->base_url . "/v1/..." to what you are looking for.
>
> Hope this helps with someone.